# Access VBA - Editing table data isn't actioned immediately

Tags: vba, ms-access, recordset

I've been searching high and low to try and figure this out, but haven't been able to find a similar question/thread here or elsewhere.

I have an Access database file (accdb in Access 2013) which holds roughly a dozen tables (with between 50 and 5000 records in each table), and a separate Access database file (also accdb) which acts as a user interface, using forms to allow the user to interact with the data stored in the 'database' file.

I've noticed that some forms are much faster to process (i.e. add, edit, and delete) data than other forms.  For example, I have two similar forms (lets call them Form A and Form B) which display a listbox which is populated from the database.  Double clicking an item in the listbox on either form opens a separate 'edit' form.  When I close Form A's edit screen, the listbox on Form A requeries and displays the new data immediately.  When I replicate the same steps on Form B, the listbox requeries, but the new data isn't included in the requery.  Both 'edit' forms are using similar code to save data to the database (below):

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblCards ORDER BY CardID", dbOpenDynaset)
rs.AddNew
rs!CardID = mintCardID
rs!CardType = Nz(txtType, "")
rs!CardNumber = Nz(txtCardNumber, "")
rs!CardAccount = Nz(txtAccount, "")
rs!Active = True
rs.Update
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

If I save data using the 'slow' form, requerying the listbox seems to have no effect.  If I close and reopen Form B two or three times, the new data eventually shows up.  Form A uses the same code (just referencing a different table) but doesn't suffer from this lag.  The lag occurs for all types of data operations (adding new data, editing existing data, and deleting records).  If I delete a record from the slow form, I can still double click the deleted record and it will open the edit form, prefilling the form with details of that record.

From the testing I've performed, I suspect that the issue lies with the actual data saving/editing/deleting from the database, and that for some reason, when I save data on the slow form, it takes some time to update the database, so my requery code is pulling data from the database before it has a chance to insert the new data.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue and been able to resolve it?

Comment: Why do you need code to save data? Is form not bound to table?

Comment: @June7 correct, I've found using code is the simplest method to do the data manipulation I need to do before saving

Answer (score 0):

Like June, I think you make it too hard for yourself. Anyway, if you insist, use the *RecordsetClone* of the form:

```vb
Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
rs.AddNew
rs!CardID.Value = mintCardID
' Avoid empty strings if at all possible.
rs!CardType.Value = Me!txtType.Value
rs!CardNumber.Value = Me!txtCardNumber.Value
rs!CardAccount.Value = Me!txtAccount.Value
rs!Active.Value = True
rs.Update
rs.Close
```